# Append text list in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

What's wrong with this code and what should I do to make it work?

```vb
'Create an instance of the Random class
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim randomNumberList As New List(Of Integer)

For x As Integer = 1 To 10
    randomNumberList.Add(rnd.Next(0, 81))
    If randomNumberList.Contains(strWords(StrwrVal.Text)) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        TxtRnd1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & randomNumberList)
    End If
Next
```

How do I make it work properly?

```vb
TxtRnd1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & randomNumberList)
```

Comment: What do you mean by work properly? What do you expect as an output?

Comment: What type of object is TxtRnd1? I have an idea, but it's good practice to include the object type of the variables that are affecting your problem.

Comment: Textbox. TxtRnd1 - Textbox. display randomnumberlist values in the textbox.

Comment: Is this code running on a button click event, page load, etc..? That has a factor if you're textbox is losing it's value because of a PostBack.  But again, the first question was asked.....what is the expected result and what is actually happening?

Comment: the code runs when you press the button. I expect that in the textbox I will display the random results, that is randomNumberList, the numbers generated from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing your code like this: I don't know why you included the `If` block but I ommited it in this answer. You can add it back if you really need it.

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim randomNumberList As New List(Of Integer)

For x As Integer = 0 To 9
    randomNumberList.Add(rnd.Next(0, 81))
    TxtRnd1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & CStr(randomNumberList(x)))
Next
```

**Update**

*Fixed Bad `If` Block*

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim randomNumberList As New List(Of Integer)

For x As Integer = 0 To 9
    Integer tmp = rnd.Next(0, 81)
    If (randomNumberList.Contains(tmp)) Then
        Continue For
    End If
    randomNumberList.Add(tmp)
    TxtRnd1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & CStr(randomNumberList(x)))
Next
```

Comment: I assumed the extra ````IF```` was to compare user input, and if the number the user guessed matched the random input then it ended the loop or else it displayed what that random number was.

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Comment: You need to set ````X = 0````, not 1.

Comment: See the updated answer. In the for loop, start at 0.

Comment: And I think if you just add the extra IF statement back in to check against user input, you should get your desired results.  Let us know.

Comment: Also, as your ````randomNumberList```` contains Integers, you need to convert the text input to integer and then compare.

Comment: If CStr(randomNumberList(x)) = strWords(StrwrVal.Text) Then

Comment: Yes, as a nitpick, use ````val.Text.Trim()```` in case there are any whitespaces after their input which will cause the logic check to be false.

Comment: @JohnPete22 That is not the way to use Val. Also, Val is a leftover from VB6. .net has much better ways to deal with strings to number. .Parse, .TryParse, CInt, Convert.ToInteger etc.

Comment: Although this answer is accepted, it fails to check for duplicate entries as the OP's code attempts.

Comment: @Mary ````val```` was shorthand for his variable ````StrwrVal```` as it was merely a reference on using ````.Trim()````

Comment: @Mary, I stated that the OP might include the`If` block if it was actually needed.

Comment: Yes, but the `If` block was wrong and part of their problem.

Comment: @Mary, Ok I updated the answer with the `If` block fixed.

Comment: They are just checking for duplicates. You don't want to `Exit For`, you want to `Continue For`